# How to get the values of a specific attribute in different nodes?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <notes>
  <note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from add="abc1">Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
  <note>
   <to add="xyz1">Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this <rref add="10">10</rref> weekend!</body>
   <pol add="adt10"/>
  </note>
 </notes>
```

I want to get all the values of the attribute `add` (except from self-closing nodes) from all the different nodes that has that attribute i.e. the output should be an list/array of the values **abc1, xyz1, 10**.
How do I do this using LINQ-TO-XML?

Is there an equivalent of the `Descendants` method for attributes?

Comment: What about `<foo add="xyz"></foo>`? Would you want to differentiate that from `<foo add="xyz" />`? Without the "except from self-closing nodes" part, this is trivial... just use `doc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Attribute("adt")).Where(attr => attr != null).Select(attr => attr.Value).ToArray()`. From there, you just need to filter out self-closing elements early in the query.

Comment: No, I don't want to differentiate `<foo add="xyz"></foo>` from `<foo add="xyz" />`...but even if I want to differentiate, then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter from the descendants which have attribute `add` and are not self closing nodes which contains the `add` attribute.

Something like:

```
var nodess = from note in Doc.Descendants()
             where note.Attribute("add") !=null && !note.IsEmpty 
             select note.Attribute("add").Value;

foreach(var node in nodess)
{       
   Console.WriteLine(node);
}
```

You would need to include `usings` of these two :

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
```

### Output:

> abc1
>
> xyz1
>
> 10

See the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqwAr6).

### UPDATE:

As per your query about exclude it in the case when has closing tag separate but empty i.e. no value in it :

```
where note.Attribute("add") !=null && (!note.IsEmpty  || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(note.Value))
```

Comment: sorry guys, that's a copy paste mistake from me, as copied from my existing  demo fiddle, correct it.

Comment: what if I do not want to get the attribute value `add` from a empty node(not in the self closing format) like `<pol add='adt10'></pol>`

Comment: add another condition like: `&& !String.IsNullOrEmpty(note.Value)` inside the `where`

Comment: @Bumba sorry it would be `where note.Attribute("add") !=null && (!note.IsEmpty  || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(note.Value))`